# Números randomicos Java

Tags: java

Olá, estou tentando fazer um exercicio que envolve números randomicos com o seguinte código:

```
    int sorteio1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) +1;
    int sorteio2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) +1;
    int sorteio3 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) +1;
    int sorteio_usuario = (int)(Math.random() * 6) +1;
```

Porém estou encontrando a seguinte dificuldade: as variáveis sorteio1, sorteio2, sorteio3, não podem ter o mesmo valor... Existe alguma maneira para efetuar isso?

Pensei até em fazer intervalos, por exemplo, o sorteio1 vai de 1 ate 2, o sorteio2 vai de 3 até 4 e o sorteio3 vai de 5 ate 6. Porém não encontrei formas de aplicar esse sorteio por intervalo no código acima. Talvez usando um for para cada variavel sorteio funcionaria, porém sinto que talvez fosse uma gambiarra...

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso **SEM** usar array, vector, list etc?

Comment: Olá Victor, pode resolver facilmente com "recursividade". Execute o sorteio1, então execute o sorteio2 e compare se é igual a sorteio1, se sim faça uma recursão para executar novamente, até que o valor seja diferente (provavelmente na segunda tentativa já vai ser, mas um loop infinito resolve, pode ser um método também em recursão). Agora execute sorteio3 e compare a sorteio1 e sorteio2, com uma IF cheque se o 3 é igual ao 1 ou ao 2, se for igual a um deles, faça uma recursão (pode ser com loop ou um método que chama ele mesmo), quando for diferente encerre o loop.

Comment: Ainda sim se for para ter um numero dinâmico de sorteios usar  UM vetor resolveria facilmente `private ArrayList<Integer> sorteios = new ArrayList<Integer>();`, nele iria adicionando os resultados a: `for (int i = 1; i <= numSorteios; i++) { sortear.add(sortear()); }`, e no método (não precisa de um método, mas preferi separar) checa se o numero já existe em `sorteios` com uma simples IF usando `ArrayList.contains()` assim `int sortear() { int novo = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1; if (sorteios.contains(novo)) { return sortear(); /*se já existir sorteia novamente*/ } else { return novo; } }`